# Using helm to delete istio leaves a number of artifacts, some of which I can't delete. How do I delete it?

Tags: istio

When I try to remove istio from my cluster (AKS if it matters), using

```
helm del --purge istio
```

it appears to work. However, when I try to install istio again, I get a host of errors about things already existing. Things like "gateways.networking.istio.io", "istio-grafana-post-install", etc. I wrote a script to manually clean up the leftovers, but it fails on jobs. In particular,

```
Error: jobs.batch "istio-security-post-install" already exists
```

I seem to be unable to delete this resource using kubectl. I'm not sure why, but it can't find it.

My question is twofold

1. What is the correct way to uninstall istio so it doesn't leave all these artifacts?

and/or

2. What is the best way to clean up all istio artifacts that don't get deleted correctly?

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: I can confirm, have the same error. Tried to delete all manually but i end up with credentials error. Will try to automate that and come back with solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to delete Istio, but after the deletion the only way I can install it back without getting errors or timeout's (resulting in pod in state ContainerCreating) is as follows:

**First installation:**

1) Followed steps from [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/download-release/)

2) Then installed Helm:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get > get_helm.sh
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule \
 --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
 --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
helm init --service-account=tiller
```

3) Install Istio: 
`helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system`

**Deletion**:

1) `kubectl delete -f $HOME/istio.yaml`

2) `helm delete --purge istio`

3) `kubectl delete ns istio-system`

3) `kubectl delete -f install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/crds.yaml -n istio-system`

*yes those are basically all 3 uninstall methods from the docs, but it makes sure all components are deleted)

4) Install Istio again (reinstallation works for both `helm template` and `helm install` methods):
`helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system`

Answering your main questions, it seems like this is still not obvious and there is no 100% "correct way:. You can read a little bit more about this in this github [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7688).

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with helm delete on [GitHub](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7688), but it should be fixed with "upgrading to 2.12.1", not sure which version of helm you are using.

Below commands work for me to delete the Istio installation.

`helm del --purge istio`

`kubectl delete -f .\install\kubernetes\istio-demo.yaml`

Comment: I ended up deleting a bunch of resources that were causing a problem. I'll try the update to helm and see if it helps